# How to uninstall a deployed contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I bought some RAM for my contract.

Now I want to uninstall my contract,and unstake the RAM. what should I do ?

Can the RAM be unstaked?

Comment: There is no command to uninstall a contract (https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-set-contract)

Do you want to sell the RAM? There is the sell command. (https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-sellram) Or do you want to make sure that the contract does not occupies any more RAM?

Comment: Uninstalling a contract can be useful in situations other than wanting to unstake RAM.  I can also see wanting to uninstall it if I am finished with the contract and want to make sure no one is able to use it any more.

Comment: delete all your records in table, then replace it with a simple abi and wasm

Answer (score 5):

Use `cleos set contract account directory --clear`

Comment: thanks. don't need directory so can just do "cleos set contract account --clear"

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an API to unset a contract. You can try to overwrite your current contract (both wasm and abi) with small files to return most of the ram you used up.

Comment: Not entirely wrong but see correct answer above. Contract and abi are then set to "" (empty string)